# Null Reference exception when assigning data to variable

Tags: c#

I have a simple helper class:

```
class WebsiteStatus
{
    public string siteName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> lastDownTime { get; set; }
}
```

I make an array of the class based on the number of sites being evaluated:

```
string URLs = "http://www.qqq.com;http://www.rrr.com;http://www.ttt.com;";
string[] sites = URLs.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
WebsiteStatus[] siteArray = new WebsiteStatus[sites.Count()];
```

When I try to input data into one of the objects in the array I'm getting a null exception error:

```
siteArray[0].siteName = sites[0];
```

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: siteArray[0] is null

Comment: _When I try to input data into one of the objects in the array_  That's your problem. There are no objects in that array

Comment: It's not initialized. You've just created the array but not the object inside. I guess you miss the siteArray[0] = new WebsiteStatus();

Comment: You have initialized the array here:

    `WebsiteStatus[] siteArray = new WebsiteStatus[sites.Count()];`

So it is initialized and not `null`, it is even correctly sized. But all elements are `null`, there is not even one `WebsiteStatus` inside. So you have to add them before you access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this instead:

```
siteArray[0] = new WebsiteStatus { siteName = sites[0], lastDownTime = null };
```

The *array* of `WebsiteStatus` objects may have been initialized, but neither of the *separate*  `WebsiteStatus` objects has been instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

siteArray[0] is null, so attempting to access siteName on that object is always going to return a NullReferenceException. You created the array, but didn't add any elements to it.